# Compound or complex sentence without conjunctions

Tags: types-of-sentences

If we have a sentence with has no conjunction but has 2 verbs then which type of sentence is it

> Go clean your room.

I think it is compound

Comment: No: it's complex since it consists of the independent clause "Go clean your room", and the dependent infinitival clause "clean your room". "Go" is a catenative verb and the infinitival clause is its catenative complement. Compound sentences have two or more independent clauses, e.g. "[You clean your room] and [I'll do the shopping]".

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for replying, I dont understand how clean your room is a dependent clause . It seems to be independent .

Comment: Yes, for every verb, there must be a clause. I've posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Go* [*clean your room*].

No: it's a complex sentence since it consists of the independent clause "Go clean your room", and the dependent infinitival clause "clean your room".

"Go" is a catenative verb and the infinitival clause is its catenative complement.

Compound sentences, by contrast, have two or more independent clauses, e.g. "[You clean your room] and [I'll do the shopping]".